# How to get the current item from iterator

Tags: rust

Is it possible to get the current item from an iterator in Rust?

I would like the same functionality as .next() but it wouldn't continue to the next item, it would just return the current item.

so:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let iterator = x.iter(); // Create an iterator

    // y is now just a single i32 from the x array
    let y = iterator.next().unwrap();

    // I'm looking for method that will return the current item from the iterator
    // Something like iterator.current() which is not implemented for some reason.
    let z = iterator.current();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your iterator in [`Peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/struct.Peekable.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let iterator = x.iter().peekable();

    let y = iterator.next().unwrap();

    let z = iterator.peek();
}
```

`peek()` returns the about-to-be-yielded item, i.e. the item that will be returned next time you'll call `next()`. Note that it returns a reference and not an owned item.

Comment: Hmm makes sense, Thanks! Is there a reason why there isn't such method as iterator.current()?

Comment: @Kuly14 Not all iterators can provide it freely. E.g. they may execute an expensive computation for the next item. So Rust prefer to provide a type that can keep track of this state itself. I don't think there is a good reason why e.g. slice iterators don't, except "it's not commonly needed".

Comment: @Kuly14 My mistake: slice iterators do. They provide the `as_slice()` methods that returns all following items.

Comment: @Kuly14 because that would require every iterator to store the item, which creates two complications: additional storage space for something which is usually useless, and either conflicting with ownership (if the iterator needs to store the last-yielded element) or trigger side-effects ahead of time (if the iterator has any). `peek` makes the step explicit, so the consumer of the iterators knows exactly what they're doing and (hopefully) not to mix side-effects and peekable iterators.

Comment: Also... it can be provided using a wrapper / adapter, so why make it part of the base contract? Same with termination: an iterator *should* stop as soon as it's returned `None` once, but that's not guaranteed. Instead the [`fuse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse) adapter can be used to latch if making completely sure this is respected is necessary. Plus technically there could be a weird use for resumable iterators